# Jest test JSX element with arrow function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple component with a render method as follows and I'm trying to test the header text being displayed correctly.

```
render() {
  const headerText = 'Header';
  const AppHeader = () => (
    <div className='Header-Text'>{headerText}</div> 
  );
  if (this.state.token) {
    return (
     <div>
       <AppHeader/>
       <div>Some Content</div> 
       <Link to="/hello"/>hi<?Link>
     </div>
  );
} else {
    return (
     <div>Some Text</div>
     <Link to="/hello"/>hi<?Link>
    );
}
```

The test for it as follows

```
  it('should render Header Text', () => {
    const props = {};
    let wrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter><App {...props}/></MemoryRouter>);
    wrapper = wrapper.find(App).dive().setState({ token: 'ok'});
  });
```

However I see in my coverage that this remains unreachable.

```
  const AppHeader = () => (
    <div>{headerText}</div> 
  );
```

The reason I didn't use mount is it doesn't allow setState for child and in this I need to have it wrapped in Router to overcome the error related to Link usage.
How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Why are you using a wrapping MemoryRouter?  The child `App` component should not be rendered. That's the explicit point of using shallow rendering in tests. What do you mean by "error related to Link usage"?

Comment: It's related to this one -> https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1112 I have updated the render with Link elements

Comment: This solves the issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559421/909535